# jQuery Active nav item combined with tab switching?

Tags: jquery, tabs, nav

I have three tabs and am trying to use jQuery to make the active tab the one that has been clicked (light gray), and then the correct section content should display.I don't want to anchor link down to the target section. From what I understand I need to change the active state of the tab that is clicked and switch which div is visible (while url does not change), am i on the right track? I just am unsure where to start, if anyone has a hint?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Practice</title>
  <style>
    html {margin:2em; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}
    h1 {margin:0;}
    h2 {color:#369;}
    hr {margin:2em 0;}
    nav ul {margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
      nav li {display:inline-block;}
      nav li a {display:block; padding:1em; color:#ccc; text-decoration:none; background-color:gray;}
      .tabs-sections {padding:0 1em; border:1px solid gray;}
      .active a {color:#000; background-color:lightgray;}
      .s2, .s3 {display:none;}
  </style>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header><h1>jQuery Exercise</h1></header>


  <hr>

  <h2>Test Tabs</h2>

  <div class="tabs">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#one">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="tabs-sections">
      <section id="one" class="s s1">
        <h2>Section One</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <b>consectetur adipisicing elit</b>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, <i>quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</i> laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </section>
      <section id="two" class="s s2">
        <h2>Section Two</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <b>consectetur adipisicing elit</b>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, <i>quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</i> laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </section>
      <section id="three" class="s s3">
        <h2>Section Three</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <b>consectetur adipisicing elit</b>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, <i>quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</i> laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
  // code
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, where is your jQuery code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is:

```
$('nav ul li a').click(function() {

    id=$(this).attr('href');

    $('nav ul li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
   $('.s').css('display','none');
    $('.s' + id).css('display','block');

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kef3wytj/ Edit: you can use hide() and show(), instead css() - much shorter and cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Here the guide:

1. Bind click event on nav > li > a
2. Prevent default it (to prevent linking down the target section)
3. Find the section to show using 'href' attribute
4. Show that section and hide all sections
5. Add class 'active' to parent 'li' of clicked a and remove 'active' class from it's siblings.